# MySQL stored procedure performance

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a few tables in my database that contain data I want to obfuscate before using it on a test server. So I wrote a stored procedure I can call to do that.

The main gest is that it:

- Creates a cursor that selects all rows (4 columns each) from table A
- Loops through those results (in my case there are about 45000)
- For each result, updates table A, and replaces the value of a particular column with an obfuscated value. It also updates table B (400000 entries) which has the same column and replaces all instances of the original value with the obfuscated one.

The problem I have is that the loop slows down ***considerably*** very quickly. It literally goes from processing about 1500 results / second to each result taking several seconds to execute.

Both tables A & B are updated using indices. Both tables & database have the same character sets. Running the update queries by hand takes milliseconds.

I hope my description of the problem is enough for someone to give me some pointers. Do I run out of resources? I FETCH the cursor in 4 parameters inside the loop, do I somehow need to 'free' those? Do I need to 'free' the update statements I do from within the loop?

EDIT: I just rewrote the stored procedure in c++ using the mysqlclient library and it works just fine

Comment: Have you run that cursor query outside procedure?
How much time it required to execute successfully?

Comment: Some time interpreter (or optimizer) makes it running too long. Once I created stored procedure, which ran 24 hours, then I rewrote last update query (it did the same thing, just there was different alias and join was changed to where conditions) and then it finished in 2 hours.

Comment: @SagarGangwal - both the select to read results into the cursor, as the update queries to tables A and B take milliseconds from a command-line prompt.